# Difficulty getting all pages a user likes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use this code, it get all pages the user likes:

```
@user = session[:graph].get_object('me')
    like = session[:graph].get_connections("me", "likes")
    if !(like.to_s.include?('appid'))
     redirect '/youneedlike'
    end
```

It's works for me and my mates, but some users have error: they are always redirected, even though they like our page.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your app request the `user_likes` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)?

Alternatively, if your app is a canvas app, you can use the [`signed_request`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) parameter to do the same thing:

```
# pseudocode
signed_request = decode signed_request()
if signed_request['page']['liked']:
  # user liked page, do something cool
else:
  # user doesn't like page. redirect somewhere to tell them why they should
```